# Failed to apply plugin

Tags: android

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/bitcode/Ameya_Workspace/ila/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip

Here my gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip is already present in application still I am getting this error

Comment: is "Use default gradle wrapper" selected under Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the error clear?

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1.

```
Open Module Settings (your project) > Project > Gradle version and enter 3.3
```